# How to combine values and metadata to a .tiff file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, geotiff

I am currently dealing with HydroSHEDS DEM [(HydroSHEDS)](http://www.hydrosheds.org/) in MATLAB (R2016b)

I have the original file (.tif format), from which I read the elevation values using the "geotiffread()" command in MATLAB. Also, I am able to extract the metadata using the "geotiffinfo()" command in MATLAB.

After running my algorithm, I have updated elevation values. I am unable to club these elevation values to the Metadata in MATLAB.

My code snippet looks like:

```
filename1 = "hydroshed.tif";    
X = geotiffread(filename1);
meta = geotiffinfo(filename1);
X_final; % Contains updated elevation values
Y = geotiffwrite("updated_hydrosheds.tif",X_final,meta); % I want something like this
```

The metadata looks like:

[METADATA of the original hydrosheds.tif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFnuZ.jpg)

The issue, according to me is that MATLAB has 73 tags which are recognized in MATLAB. However, I have a list of 36 tags which are not all included in the recognized tags.

Some references:

1. [Documentation for geotiffwrite()](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/geotiffwrite.html)
2. [Documentation for Tiff()](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiff.html)
3. [Adding New Tiff Tags](http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/addingtags.html)